# Leaflet Slider performance on IE

Tags: javascript, leaflet

[The Leaflef playback plugin](https://github.com/hallahan/LeafletPlayback) 's slider acts weird on my IE while it works fine on Chrome and Firefox. 
Here is what I have included in my page:

```
 link(type='text/css', rel='stylesheet', href='https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.1/dist/leaflet.css')
 link(rel='stylesheet', type='text/css',href='//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css')
 script(src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js')
 script(src='//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js')   
 script(src='../javascripts/LeafletPlayback.js')
```

[image: IE's slider]

Comment: Which version of IE?

Comment: I have version 11